# How can I set a localStorage value to the number 1 if nothing is returned?

Tags: javascript

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
this.phrasesOrderById = 
   parseInt(storage.getItem('phrasesOrderById').toInt(),10) || 1;
```

However this gives me a message saying cannot read property toInt of null.

Can someone give me some advice on how I can set the value to 1 if a null is returned from getItem? Note that I spread this one line across two as it doesn't seem to display properly when it's just one line.

Comment: What is toInt() ? If getItem does not return anything, of course you can not chain it.

Answer (score 2):

following works

```
    phrasesOrderById = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("phrasesOrderById") || 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript

```
this.phrasesOrderById = storage.getItem('phrasesOrderById')?parseInt(storage.getItem('phrasesOrderById').toInt(),10):1;
```

Or you can simply use If/Else

```
if(storage.getItem('phrasesOrderById') {

    this.phrasesOrderById = parseInt(storage.getItem('phrasesOrderById').toInt(), 10);
}
else{

    this.phrasesOrderById = 1;
}
```